# Why does this result in inheritance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was reading [this article](http://jonathancreamer.com/adding-clarity-to-scope-inheritance-in-angular/) on scope inheritance in AngularJS and was confused by this code example:

```
angular.module("Demo", [])  
  .controller("ChildCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.rootyThing = "I am groot";
    console.log($scope.rootyThing);  // "I am groot"
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf($scope)); // Scope
 });
```

I don't understand why `$scope.rootyThing` is set instead of `undefined`.

The article's explanation seems incomplete. The fact that the child scope "prototypically inherits" from `$rootScope` would not explain this, seeing as `rootyThing` is not set on the prototype, and moreover was set after the creation of the child scope `$scope`.

The only explanation is if the scopes in Angular are deeply modified such that all variables set on them are broadcast to existing child scopes. Unless I'm missing something, more than possible.

Can anyone explain this?

**Edit:** My current understanding is that `$rootScope` *is* in fact the `Scope` function itself rather than an *instance* of `Scope`, and all `$scope` instances use this as a root prototype, so when variables are set on the function `Scope` then they're naturally accessible to the various `$scope` instances.

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1):

All scopes are added on `$rootScope` object. If you add a property(for example someProperty)on `$rootScope` and you try to access it using `$scope.someProperty`, then it will be checked that this property exists on `$scope`(i.e current scope). If that property does not exist, then it will be checked on higher level in scope chain(i.e `$rootScope`).

Answer (score 1):

`ng-controller` will create a `new Scope`.

this scope's prototype is set to `parent Scope`(i.e, `$rootScope` in this case)

And it's the default javascript behavior to look in the prototype chain if the property which we are looking for is not found in the object.

[image: Scope inheritance]

Answer (score 0):

It is set to the prototypes, try console.log

```
$scope.__proto__.rootyThing
```

And you should see it there.

Furthermore, objects are by reference in javascript so it doesnt matter when $scope was set 
for example

```
//say this is your rootScope
objRoot = {
   obj: {
       test: 'hello'
   }
}

//Now lets create a scope
var temp = objRoot.obj

//Update rootScope
objRoot.obj.test = "changed"

//log your temp
console.log(temp.test); //changed
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs, as far as I know, the scopes are inherited from the parent scope, *all the variables*, but if u have a **sibling scope** then those values will not be inherited. The broadcasting is done for events.

So, Angular is working as it has to be. If you have set some variable on the $rootScope that will be accesible throughout the App.